# What is the proper way to smoothly scale an element to nothing and then back to its original size

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

This is how I do it in React:

```
  const animate_boxes = () => {
    inner_ref.current.style.transform = "scale(0)";
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (inner_ref && inner_ref.current) {
        inner_ref.current.style.transform = "scale(1)";
      }
    }, 200);
  };
```

For some reason, it is not dependable. the `setTimeout` may not always get run. Still haven't figured out why yet. But If there is an alternative way to do it, then please write a solution.

thanks

Comment: Are you open to using a react library instead of manually attempting to animate?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the react-spring library?

Answer (score 0):

Use framer motion library with `scale` property passed in as an array of values
eg :

```
import {motion} from 'framer-motion'


const Component = () => {
   return (
     <motion.div
         initial={{scale: 1}}
         animate={{scale: [0.1, 1]}}
     >
         hi
     </motion.div>

   )

}
```

Refer this docs for more examples - [Docs](https://www.framer.com/docs/examples/)